# Mysql find users after table pattern

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following five tables:

```
users: id, name
region: id, usersId, region
country: id, usersId, country
status: id, usersId, status
search: id, usersId, region, country, status
```

The search table includes the given data after what we will search in the other tables.

So, if the search-table has 5 users from 'DE', 'US', 'CH' ...  with different or same zipcodes, all users from users, region, country and status should be displayed, where this pattern is true

For example:

I have 10 users in my database and the user with the `user.id = 1` stores his data in search-table:

users:

```
id:8, "John"
```

search:

```
id: 8, usersId:1, region: 47798, country: "DE", status: "Boss"
```

Now i want all other user who comes from 'DE' from the region `LIKE "4%"` and who works as a "Boss" :-)

This is my database:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for `country`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `country`;
CREATE TABLE `country` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `usersId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
-- ----------------------------
--  Records of `country`
-- ----------------------------
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `country` VALUES ('1', '1', 'US'), ('2', '2', 'US'), ('3', '3', 'AUT'), ('4', '4', 'DE'), ('5', '5', 'DE'), ('6', '6', 'CH');
COMMIT;
-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for `region`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `region`;
CREATE TABLE `region` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `usersId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `region` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
-- ----------------------------
--  Records of `region`
-- ----------------------------
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `region` VALUES ('1', '1', '47798'), ('2', '2', '47798'), ('3', '3', '444'), ('4', '4', '78965'), ('5', '5', '7856'), ('6', '6', '7856');
COMMIT;
-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for `search`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `search`;
CREATE TABLE `search` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `usersId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `region` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
-- ----------------------------
--  Records of `search`
-- ----------------------------
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `search` VALUES ('1', 'US', '1', '47798', 'Angestellter'), ('2', 'US', '2', '79653', 'Angestellter'), ('3', 'AUT', '3', '444', 'Chef'), ('4', 'DE', '4', '78965', 'Gesellschafter'), ('5', 'DE', '5', '7856', 'Vertrieb'), ('6', 'DE', '6', '47798', 'Angestellter');
COMMIT;
-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for `status`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `status`;
CREATE TABLE `status` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `usersId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
-- ----------------------------
--  Records of `status`
-- ----------------------------
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `status` VALUES ('1', '1', 'Angestellter'), ('2', '2', 'Angestellter'), ('3', '3', 'Chef'), ('4', '4', 'Gesellschafter'), ('5', '5', 'Vertrieb'), ('6', '6', 'Vertrieb');
COMMIT;
-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for `users`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
-- ----------------------------
--  Records of `users`
-- ----------------------------
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES ('1', 'Heinz'), ('2', 'Karl'), ('3', 'Helmut'), ('4', 'Viktor'), ('5', 'Thomas'), ('6', 'Kurt');
COMMIT;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

And this is my Select, what not working correctly, i only geht the search-table entries:

```
select * from users
inner join region on users.id=region.usersid
inner join country on users.id=country.usersid
inner join status on users.id=status.usersid
where users.id in (select usersId from search where country = 'DE' AND region LIKE '7%');
```

Comment: The table structures are very strange.  You should be storing the `region`, `country`, `status`, and `search` `ID` values in the `users` table, not storing the `UserId` in all of those tables.  You should really consider redoing your table structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query (modified the select you were using in your question):

```
select * from users
inner join search
on search.usersid = users.id
where country = 'DE' AND region LIKE '7%'
```

You can change the where clause as per your requirement.

Also, it is a good practice to maintain consistency in nomenclature of the columns within different tables especially the primary keys/identity columns. For example: In your table definition, `Id` in `users` table but `usersId` in `search` table.